# Instance member 'decodeJson' cannot be used on type 'Utils'

Tags: json, swift, class, oop, instance

I confront a problem and i tried different solutions but i couldn't solve yet. The problem is `Instance member 'decodeJson' cannot be used on type 'Utils'` on `decodeJson` area. As you can see Utils class has different functions which `getDataWithURLSession`, `decodeJson` and `getDataWithURLSession` need to use `decodeJson`.

```
public class Utils {

    static var ApiURL = "http://xxx"

    var categoryList = [MangaCategory]()

    //MARK - JSON Searilization
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    static func getDataWithURLSession(withtoken: String){
        guard let url = URL(string: Utils.ApiURL + "/Category/Get") else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer " + withtoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [], options: []) else { return }
        request.httpBody = httpBody

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in

            decodeJson(data: data)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    private func decodeJson(data:Data?){
        guard let data = data else {return}
        dump(data)

        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Categorys.self, from: data)
            for manga in json.data{
                if json.data.count > categoryList.count
                {
                    let cat = MangaCategory(context: CoreDataService.context)

                    cat.category_name = manga.name
                    cat.category_id = Int16(manga.id)!

                    CoreDataService.saveContext()
                    self.categoryList.append(cat)
                }
                else{
                    print("JSon Serialization Es Geçildi.")
                }
            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print("JSON Serializing error : ", jsonError)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your issue right, you are trying to use private method of an instance of the Utils class in the method of that class where that instance is not defined.

To solve it you have several options:

1. Make both methods to be the instance methods (make the first one not static but public).
2. Make both method to be the Utils class methods - make the second function static too. But in this case you will have to return an instance of the Utils class in the method decodeJson to have an ability to store the categoryList variable there.

If you will decide to use the second option and will have problems in code, let me know, I will add the code in my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried first solution but not working. So, I changed the name of function
`static func getDataWithURLSession(withtoken: String){` to 
`public func getDataWithURLSession(withtoken: String){` and 
`private func decodeJson(data:Data?){` to 
`public func decodeJson(data:Data?) -> [Any]` and added `return categoryList`. Actually my utils class problem is solved but when i call the getDataWithURLSession function at AppDelegate.swift  I saw different problem like `Instance member 'getDataWithURLSession' cannot be used on type 'Utils'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

Comment: Both options are depending on where are you going to use your Utils object with stored property. Why the first method is not working? I thought that you needed to have an object and fill it's categoryList by calling getDataWithURLSession. Could you show the code you're using in the app delegate and anywhere else. I mean how you're going to use it. I think you're calling it as a class method while we are trying to make it an instance one.